# Use determinant to show that two vectors in $ ℝ^{3} $ are parallel?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If I want to show that two vectors are parallel in $  ℝ^{2} $ I can write them in as the rows of a 2x2 determinant, and if the determinant is zero then the vectors are parallel. My book says that this method not work for vectors in $ ℝ^{3} $, and I don't understand why? If you write the determinant in the form

\begin{vmatrix}
e_{x} & e_{y}  & e_{z}  \\ 
x_{1} & x_{2} & x_{3}\\ 
y_{1} & y_{2} & y_{3}\notag
\end{vmatrix}

If two rows are parallel then the determinant is zero?

Comment: As you wrote it's completely fine. I think, what your book wanted to say it's you can't compute the determinant of 2 vectors in $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: Okey, thank you!

Comment: I think that the "if and only if" part is  not true in $R^{3}$. That is in $R^3$ you can have vectors for which your determinant is $0$ though the vectors are not parallel. Take $x=<e_x,e_y,e_z>$ and $y=<e_x,0,0>$ for example.

Comment: The idea is that the determinant is of the form $\,a_xe_x+a_ye_y+a_ze_z\,$ and all of the coefficients $\,a_x,a_y,a_z\,$ must be zero. In fact, this is the cross product of vectors in $R^3$ and this is zero iff they are paralle.